# ExecutorService submit method returned futures not maintaining the order of submission

Tags: java, future, executorservice

Hello everyone i am pretty new to all the java concurrency stuff so pardon me if my question sounds a bit naive. The matter is i am trying to submit tasks to an executor service in a loop and immediately returning the future returned in a list. Now in another loop i am iterating over the list of futures and calling get on the future to obtain the actual result. Now what bothers me is that i expect the future to be in the same order as submission but what i get is completely random order.Here is my code

```
for (int count = 0; count < product_ID_List.size(); count++) {
                System.out.println(product_ID_List.get(count));
                WebServiceCall WebServiceCall = new WebServiceCall(basePath, product_ID_List.get(count),
                        companyId);
                futureList.add(executor.submit(WebServiceCall));
            }
```

the webservice call basically inserts a record in the database and returns the auto generated id

And here is the code for iterating over the future List

```
for (int count = 0; count < futureList.size(); count++) {
                Response resp = futureList.get(count).get();
                BResponse bresponse = new BResponse();
                bresponse = resp.readEntity(BResponse.class);
                System.out.println("the generated id is @ " + bresponse.generatedPOID);

            }
```

Now in a completely fresh table i normally expect the result to be 1,2,3 since the first submitted task would generate the id 1 and so on but the result i get is random such as 3,1,2   2,3,1 and so on.. Need help as to how can i get the futures maintained in the order the task was submitted.Note not talking about the order of execution of tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your futures is not changing its order. You are getting the `future.get()` in the same order you have submitted the task. However, you have seen that order of id is not sequential as the **task you submitted first does guarantee that it will execute first**. So, it is possible that you submitted the first task can execute last (or any sequence), so there may be `n` number of task already executed before that, so when that task executes it will get the id (`n+1`) instead of `1` and `future.get()` will return you `(n+1)`

Comment: what you mean to say that the task submitted first has no guarantee of finishing first??

Comment: @JayD Yes, you are right. There is no guarantee of that.